# Java - Splitting data into a 2D array

Tags: java, arrays, split

I have a String of data called `purchaseData` which is separated into into lines with `"\n"` and into fields with `","` (in CSV format).

How could I make a 2D string array so that the array contains arrays with each of the fields in. So for `String[i][j]`, `i` would be the line value (position of row) and `j` would be the position of the field within the selected array of data (the row).

Comment: Have you tried anything? What I would recommend is an embedded loop (outer gets the next line inner gets the fields from that line). I can give you the code but I want to know what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    String str = "YOUR_VERY_LONG_STRING";
    String[] lines = str.split("\n");
    String[][] linesCsv = new String[lines.length][];

    for (int i=0; i<lines.length; i++) {
        linesCsv[i] = lines[i].split(",");
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use String#split to create 2D array like this:

```
String str = "a,b,c,d,e,f\ng,h,i,j,k,l\nm,n,o,p,q,r";
String[] arr = str.split("\n");
String[][] csv = new String[arr.length][];
for(int r=0; r<arr.length; r++)
    csv[r] = arr[r].split(",");
```

**Update:** Since Max commented (and I agree) that my original answer won't work with `RFC 4180 type CSV` here I am posting an update to parse those complex CSV data like in my example below:

```
String str =
  "m,n,o,\"p\nx\",q,r\n\"abc,123\",\"45,12\",\"a,aa\",\"b,bb\",\"c,cc\",\"fo\no,bar\"";

String[] arr = str.split("\n\\s*(?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)");
String[][] csv = new String[arr.length][];
for(int r=0; r<arr.length; r++)
    csv[r] = arr[r].split(",\\s*(?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)");
```

**Testing:**

```
for(int r=0; r<csv.length; r++)
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(csv[r]));
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
[m, n, o, "p
x", q, r]
["abc,123", "45,12", "a,aa", "b,bb", "c,cc", "fo
o,bar"]
```

Comment: +1, however if the format in question is RFC 4180 type CSV, then only a proper parser will be able to parse it. For example, this is proper CSV with 3 columns: `"abc,123"`,`"2345\n12"`,`"a,aa""b,bb""c,cc"`

Comment: Fully agree @Max that only a proper parser can work with those kind of CSV data.

Comment: @Max: I have posted an *update* to my answer which should work with RFC 4180 type CSV as well.